# Legend em form-group bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Alguém sabe como faço para deixar a legenda do formulário abaixo dentro da border line ? Ou seja, gostaria que a legenda ficasse dentro da linha do contorno do form.

```html
<legend>Filtro por data</legend>
<div class="row second-group">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Conta Corrente </label>
      <dx-select-box placeholder="Selecione Conta..." [items]="contasCorrente" displayExpr="descricao" valueExpr="id" [searchEnabled]="true" formControlName="contaCorrenteId">
      </dx-select-box>
      <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.contaCorrenteId">
                                  <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.contaCorrenteId"></p>
                                </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="dataEmissaoInicial">Data Emissão Inicial</label>
      <dx-date-box type="date" width="100%" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" formControlName="dataEmissaoInicial" (onValueChanged)="definirValor($event)"></dx-date-box>
      <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.dataEmissaoInicial">
                                    <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.dataEmissaoInicial"></p>
                                </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="dataEmissaoFinal">Data Emissão Final</label>
      <dx-date-box [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" type="date" width="100%" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" formControlName="dataEmissaoFinal" (onValueChanged)="definirValor($event)"></dx-date-box>
      <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.dataEmissaoFinal">
                                            <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.dataEmissaoFinal"></p>
                                          </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" style="margin-top: 27px" class="btn btn-block btn-success" (click)="filtrarConciliacao()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Filtrar </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Atualmente está assim:

[image: Legend]

Comment: E como deveria ficar?

Comment: Então pq não coloca dentro da div?

Comment: Gostaria que ficasse assim:

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEbZQ.jpg

Comment: Veja se era isso marcado na duplicada. Se não for eu reabro a pergunta. Abs!

Comment: @hugocsl Pode colocar todas essas divs dentro de um fieldset? Por ser Bootstrap, agora fiquei na dúvida.

Comment: Pelo menos na [doc do Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/) aparece.

Comment: por gentileza o fieldset fica dentro ou fora da div? Pois não funcionou.

Comment: Coloquei as divs dentro do fieldset e antes da primeira div coloquei a <legend>. Mesmo assim não funcionou. A legenda ficou fora.

Comment: @maverick_ entendi seu problema, na verdade é que o próprio Bootstrap "desconstrói" esses elementos mudando o CSS que seria padrão... Deixei os detalhes na resposta.

Comment: @Sam como ele está usando Bootstrap 3 não tem problema, pq o Grid é baseado em Floats, já se fosse no Bootstrap 4 poderia ter problemas, pq a Row é um container Flex e a Col precisaria ser filho direto. Nesse caso eu testei a responsividade e mesmo dentro do Fieldset funciona direitinho, no BS4 provavelmente não daria certo...

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que vc está usando Bootstrap, e por default ele coloca alguns estilos indesejados no `fieldset` e no `legend`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que foi feito um tratamento no CSS para sobrescrever esses estilos do Bootstrap o `fieldset` e o `legend` ficaram mais próximo do que seria o parão do `user-agent`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style>
fieldset {
    border:1px solid #999;
    padding: 10px; /* aqui vc controla a distancia entre os elementos e a borda */
    margin: 15px; /* essa margem é para alinhar o fieldset com o restante do grid */
}
legend {
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row second-group ">
    
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Filtro por data</legend>
    
    
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Conta Corrente </label>
                        <dx-select-box placeholder="Selecione Conta..." [items]="contasCorrente" displayExpr="descricao"
                            valueExpr="id" [searchEnabled]="true" formControlName="contaCorrenteId">
                        </dx-select-box>
                        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.contaCorrenteId">
                            <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.contaCorrenteId"></p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="dataEmissaoInicial">Data Emissão Inicial</label>
                        <dx-date-box type="date" width="100%" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            formControlName="dataEmissaoInicial" (onValueChanged)="definirValor($event)"></dx-date-box>
                        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.dataEmissaoInicial">
                            <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.dataEmissaoInicial"></p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="dataEmissaoFinal">Data Emissão Final</label>
                        <dx-date-box [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" type="date" width="100%" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            formControlName="dataEmissaoFinal" (onValueChanged)="definirValor($event)"></dx-date-box>
                        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.dataEmissaoFinal">
                            <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.dataEmissaoFinal"></p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" style="margin-top: 27px" class="btn btn-block btn-success"
                        (click)="filtrarConciliacao()">
                        <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Filtrar </button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Massa rs :)))))